# Express app.use refresh behavior

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using Express with Node.js and am quite confused about refreshing behavior. Upon refresh of `/test`, it seems like something is cached server-side when it hits `app.use` because the array length is nonzero (see sample code below). I would expect the array length to reset to zero since I'm hitting `/test`again when I'm refreshing the browser.

Does app.use cache things by default? How does Express middleware work in terms of refresh? I couldn't find anything that explained this clearly in the Express 4.14 docs.

==================

Browser Endpoint: `localhost:8000/test`

Client:

```
$.get('/data').done(function(response){...}
```

Route:

```
module.exports = function(app) {
  app.get('/test', function(req,res) {
    var arr =[];
    app.use('/data', function(req,res, next) {
      console.log(arr.length); // this is nonzero on refresh
      arr.push(/* some stuff*/);
      res.send({"arr": arr});
    }
   res.render('test.html')
  }
}
```

Server:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

require('./routes/route')(app);
app.set('views',__dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

var server = app.listen(8000, function() {
    console.log("server started 8000");
});
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Comment: Express middleware should be defined just once, at the start of the application, and not for every request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really server caching.  It's because you are registering middleware inside a closure and thus those closure variables (like `arr`) are retained for the next invocation of the middleware.  In addition, you're registering the middleware over and over (a new one each time `/test` is hit).

When you register `app.use()` inside an `app.get()` that means that every time you hit the `/test` route, you will add another duplicate `app.use()` handler.  They will accumulate over time and the same middleware will get run multiple times for for the same request, retaining the previous value for `arr` from when it was originally registered, but each with their own value for that array.

The general solution here is to NOT register `app.use()` inside of `app.get()` because you only want one handler - you don't want them to accumulate.

---

It's unclear what you're trying to accomplish with your `app.use('/data/, ...)` middleware.  It is clear that your current structure is wrong, but without understanding what you were trying to do with that, it's not clear exactly how it should be written.  The usual function of middleware is to be registered once during the initialization of the server and never inside a request handler.

---

If you're trying to respond to your ajax call:

```
$.get('/data').done(function(response){...}
```

Then, you would want an `app.get('/data', ...)` at the top level of your `app` module to make that work.

---

Please explain what the `arr.push()` is supposed to accomplish for us to help in any more detail.

Comment: @Bethany - Did this answer your question?  If so, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the green checkmark to the left of the answer and that will also earn you some reputation points for following the proper procedure.

Comment: thank you so much for the thorough response! i'm not very familiar with how express/middleware works, good to know it should be placed at the top level.

i actually want to maintain the functionality of this code as it is currently working (on refresh, i do not want the array to be cleared). i'll look into sessions,etc to achieve that. Thanks again!

Comment: @Bethany - Yes, it appears that creating a user session object and putting the array into that user-specific session might be what you're after.